Rewrite with Custom Posts
So basically i have two custom posts Departments and Staff. The Department has a title and description, and the  Staff has name, role, and Relationship link to Department. I already have a page that uses shortcode to list all the departments and each has a link that looks like this teams/?department=finance and I am facing a couple of issues

I already have a page called teams and I want the teams/?department=finance link to navigate to this page but it doesn't. It just goes to a page with the header and footer. I have added the following rewrite rule but no form of rewriting takes place even after flushing. The rewrite code is on the function.php page but doesn't seem to be taking any effect at all

function custom_rewrite_rules() {
    add_rewrite_rule(
        '^teams/([^/]+)/?$',
        'index.php?pagename=teams&department=$matches[1]',
        'top'
    );
}
add_action( 'init', 'custom_rewrite_rules' );



I am using shortcode to add the php to render the staff filter that searches for the staff members that have have the department name and the code is as follows. The code it self has no issues but i just cannot navigate to the page that actual has the short_code

function staff_filter_shortcode($atts) {
    // Get the department name from the shortcode attribute
    $atts = shortcode_atts(array(
        'department' => ''
    ), $atts);

    // Sanitize and convert the department name to title case
    $department_name = isset($_GET['department']) ? sanitize_text_field($_GET['department']) : '';
    $department_name = ucwords(str_replace('-', ' ', $department_name));

    // Start building the output
    $output = '<div class="staff-filter">';

    if ($department_name) {
        // Get the department post by title
        $department = get_page_by_title($department_name, OBJECT, 'department');

        if ($department) {
            // Get staff posts associated with this department
            $args = array(
                'post_type' => 'staff',
                'meta_query' => array(
                    array(
                        'key' => 'department',
                        'value' => $department->ID,
                        'compare' => 'LIKE'
                    )
                )
            );

            $staff_query = new WP_Query($args);

            if ($staff_query->have_posts()) {
                $output .= '<h1>Staff in ' . esc_html($department_name) . ' Department</h1>';
                $output .= '<div class="staff-list">';
                while ($staff_query->have_posts()) {
                    $staff_query->the_post();
                    $role = get_field('role');
                    $output .= '<div class="staff-member">';
                    $output .= '<h2>' . get_the_title() . '</h2>';
                    if ($role) {
                        $output .= '<p><strong>Role:</strong> ' . esc_html($role) . '</p>';
                    }
                    $output .= '<div class="staff-content">' . get_the_content() . '</div>';
                    $output .= '</div>';
                }
                $output .= '</div>';
            } else {
                $output .= '<p>No staff members found for this department.</p>';
            }

            wp_reset_postdata();
        } else {
            $output .= '<p>Department not found.</p>';
        }
    } else {
        $output .= '<p>No department specified.</p>';
    }

    $output .= '</div>';

    return $output;
}
add_shortcode('staff_filter', 'staff_filter_shortcode');



Make sure the [staff_filter] shortcode is being used on the correct page (the page called "teams").
Try this:
In funtion.php
function custom_rewrite_rules() {
    add_rewrite_rule(
        '^teams/([^/]+)/?$',
        'index.php?pagename=teams&department=$matches[1]',
        'top'
    );
}
add_action('init', 'custom_rewrite_rules');

// Function to flush the rewrite rules
function flush_rewrite_rules_custom() {
    custom_rewrite_rules();
    flush_rewrite_rules();
}
add_action('after_switch_theme', 'flush_rewrite_rules_custom');

Shortcode Function:
function staff_filter_shortcode($atts) {
    // Get the department name from the shortcode attribute
    $atts = shortcode_atts(array(
        'department' => ''
    ), $atts);

    // Sanitize and convert the department name to title case
    $department_name = isset($_GET['department']) ? sanitize_text_field($_GET['department']) : '';
    $department_name = ucwords(str_replace('-', ' ', $department_name));

    // Start building the output
    $output = '<div class="staff-filter">';

    if ($department_name) {
        // Get the department post by title
        $department = get_page_by_title($department_name, OBJECT, 'department');

        if ($department) {
            // Get staff posts associated with this department
            $args = array(
                'post_type' => 'staff',
                'meta_query' => array(
                    array(
                        'key' => 'department',
                        'value' => '"' . $department->ID . '"',
                        'compare' => 'LIKE'
                    )
                )
            );

            $staff_query = new WP_Query($args);

            if ($staff_query->have_posts()) {
                $output .= '<h1>Staff in ' . esc_html($department_name) . ' Department</h1>';
                $output .= '<div class="staff-list">';
                while ($staff_query->have_posts()) {
                    $staff_query->the_post();
                    $role = get_field('role');
                    $output .= '<div class="staff-member">';
                    $output .= '<h2>' . get_the_title() . '</h2>';
                    if ($role) {
                        $output .= '<p><strong>Role:</strong> ' . esc_html($role) . '</p>';
                    }
                    $output .= '<div class="staff-content">' . get_the_content() . '</div>';
                    $output .= '</div>';
                }
                $output .= '</div>';
            } else {
                $output .= '<p>No staff members found for this department.</p>';
            }

            wp_reset_postdata();
        } else {
            $output .= '<p>Department not found.</p>';
        }
    } else {
        $output .= '<p>No department specified.</p>';
    }

    $output .= '</div>';

    return $output;
}
add_shortcode('staff_filter', 'staff_filter_shortcode');

